# how to keep content of page from re-sizing when the page is re-size to a smaller width

Tags: javascript, css

hey guys please i need help on page re-size.. how do I stop the content of the page from re-sizing when the page width is re-size to a smaller width just like **facebook**

Comment: Remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` on head tag of your html.

Comment: The infomation given are not sufficient to give a propper answer. If you're talking about images, then maybe setting a fixed width with `hegiht: auto;` will be an option.

Comment: `FIXED WEBSITE LAYOUT` look into it :- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop content from resizing, put the Sizes in the places marked X and Y (in pixels)

```
img {
height:Xpx;
width:Ypx;
}
```

If you want to retain the aspect ratio of your images, you should check out -
[How do you prevent resizing of images in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272169/how-do-you-prevent-resizing-of-images-in-css)

Here's the code from there

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

or

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto
}
```

Both of them are almost the same